# Listar objetos Javascript em uma tabela

Tags: javascript, html, json

Boa tarde. Tenho um objeto:

```
var relatorios = [
        { "Data": "28/08/2015", "Descricao": "Visita a Cliente", "Classificacao": "Class.2", "Valor": "R$435,00", "Verba": "RH", "Comentario": "Cliente A" },
        { "Data": "15/05/2013", "Descricao": "Apresentação", "Classificacao": "Class.4", "Valor": "R$328,00", "Verba": "Financeiro", "Comentario": "Cliente S" },
        { "Data": "19/10/2014", "Descricao": "Visita e Apresentação", "Classificacao": "Class.7", "Valor": "R$548,78", "Verba": "Diretoria", "Comentario": "Cliente D" },
        { "Data": "11/04/2015", "Descricao": "Proposta", "Classificacao": "Class.34", "Valor": "R$369,22", "Verba": "Comercial", "Comentario": "Cliente F" },
        { "Data": "12/12/2015", "Descricao": "Visita", "Classificacao": "Class.2", "Valor": "R$120,20", "Verba": "RH", "Comentario": "Cliente G" },
        { "Data": "25/06/2015", "Descricao": "Evento", "Classificacao": "Class.1", "Valor": "R$125,00", "Verba": "Comercial", "Comentario": "Cliente H" },
        { "Data": "29/07/2015", "Descricao": "Fechar Venda", "Classificacao": "Class.9", "Valor": "R$333,33", "Verba": "comercial", "Comentario": "Cliente J" }
        ];
```

E gostaria de lista-lo em uma table, na verdade, só colocar dentro de um tbody. Mas nao encontro solução onde quer que eu procure.
Att.

Answer (score 5):

Vais precisar de iterar essa array e ir adicionando elementos.

```
relatorios.forEach(function (relatorio) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var campo in relatorio) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = relatorio[campo];
        tr.appendChild(td);
    };
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gsupdtp9/

Assim, uma vez que `relatorios` é uma array, percorres um a um com o `.forEach()` e a cada linha/elemento dessa array crias um novo `tr` para a table.

Depois iteras também o objeto que cada relatório é, e criando uma nova `td` inseres o valor com `td.innerHTML = relatorio[campo];`.

Depois é só inserir o elemento criado no elemento onde ele pertence.

Comment: +1 por não usar Jquery e por manipular os DOM ao invés de concatenar string.